# How to script jquery to reload page if regular expression match not found

Tags: jquery, regex, expression, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'd like to look/search a webpage body for a regular expression that matches (in this example PO123456 should). If found I'd like an alert saying it was found and the script to stop running. If a RegEx match was not found I'd like it to reload the page repeatedly until a match is found. I will then paste this script into TamperMonkey to use on a page that currently requires me to press refresh repeatedly like a lab animal.

The following does not work, yet...

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Reload Page If RegEx Match Not Found
// @namespace   
// @version      0.1
// @description  Reloads Page Until RegEx Match Found
// @author       TJ
// @match        https://system.fakepage.com/someotherpage
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var regex = /^PO\d{6}g/;
    var PO = str.match(regex);

    if($('body:contains("' + PO + '")').length > 0)
    {
    alert("Found: " + PO);
    }
    else
    {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Please help the bird out smart the pavlovian control system by helping me figure this script out! (once tested I'd like to do away with the alert.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Reload Page If RegEx Match Not Found
// @namespace   
// @version      0.1
// @description  Reloads Page Until RegEx Match Found
// @author       TJ
// @match        https://system.fakepage.com/someotherpage
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==   
$(document).ready(function() {
    var regex = /PO\d{6}/g;
    var PO = document.body.innerHTML.match(regex);
    if (PO) {
        console.log("Found:",PO);
    } else {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: It turns out, there are multiple numbers in the html that the regex matches with even though there is only one PO123456 visible to the user on the web page. How do I restrict this script to search only the visible portion of the page?Or if I use inspector to find the html classes can I use this information to only look for PO123456 after a certain place in the code?